# SQL queries with WHERE conditions to specific cells using VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am trying to pull data to specific cells on Excel from a specific table on SQL server database. I have the following form type:

[image]

The data should be pulled based on the user typed ID (in cell B2). For example, I'm using the following VBA code to get the user name from the database table:

```
Sub Get_Data()

        Set objMyconn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rc As Long

        objMyconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=IP_ADDRESS;Initial Catalog=My_Database; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        objMyconn.Open

        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "select User_Name from My_Database WHERE User_ID = '" & Range("B2").Value & "'"""

        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute

        Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

        ActiveSheet.Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)     
End Sub
```

I get this error when I run the code:

[image]

Also, any idea on how to pull a data array of the session information in the respective cells (using Select query based on the user ID again)? e.g. cell B8, C8, D8, B9, C9, D9, etc.. One user may have multiple sessions.

Comment: Not everyone can see the pictures on SO. Please include the error as text, and include which line the error occurs on.

Comment: I think the final line would be better as `ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = objMyRecordset("User_Name")` as that is more explicit. I normally use `CopyFromRecordset` only to load all contents of multiple records/columns  in a recordset into a worksheet in a single step. If you want to load User_Status into Range("B4") then you can get that in the same Select statement and refer to it with objMyRecordset("User_Status").

Comment: JohnRC: that sounds like a good approach, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line: `objMyCmd.CommandText = "select User_Name from My_Database WHERE User_ID = '" & Range("B2").Value & "'"""` you have a double quote at the end. Remove it.

`objMyCmd.CommandText = "select User_Name from My_Database WHERE User_ID = '" & Range("B2").Value & "'"`

On the second part, the approach I'd take is to retrieve all the necessary data items to fill the fields into the recordset. Then, I'd iterate through the recordset until I reached the end and populate the recordset![Field] values into the appropriate locations (I haven't tested this code, but you should be able to follow along:)

```
objMyCmd.CommandText ="SELECT User_Name, Session_ID, Sesssion_Date, Session_Date " & _  
    "FROM [My_Database] Where User_ID = '" & range("b2").value & "';"
objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd
'objMyRecordset.MoveLast
'objMyRecordset.MoveFirst

Dim Offset as Integer
Offset = 0
While Not objMyRecordset.EOF 
    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 2+Offset).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields("Session_ID").Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 2+Offset).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields("Sesssion_Date").Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 2+Offset).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields("Session_Date").Value
    Offset = Offset + 1
    objMyRecordset.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my first issue. How about if I need to add another Select statement to the same code to fetch array of data, e.g. to row 8? I need to get all the session ID:s belonging to the same user.

Comment: Thanks again Chris. I tried the code and I got this error: rowset does not support fetching backward.

Comment: Looks like ADODB.Recordset.Open uses a default cursor type of forward only. Remove the `.MoveLast` and `.MoveFirst` lines and re run the code

Comment: Awesome! Woks just fine now. Thanks Chris.